# Can I share network access from Ethernet over WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet

I have 3 devices:

- A Linux server
- A MacBook
- An iPad

I currently have no router. But, the Linux server and MacBook are connected by Ethernet through a switch. The MacBook and iPad are connected by Wi-Fi,  the Wi-Fi network is created by the MacBook.

The MacBook is able to connect to Linux just fine, through ssh and view webpages hosted on the Linux server. The iPad is able to view pages hosted on the MacBook but is unable to connect to the Linux server. It appears that the MacBook keeps the two networks separate. I tried using the internet sharing feature on the MacBook. Sharing Ethernet to devices through Wi-Fi, but it doesn't help because it's not the Internet I want to share it's a local network.

Is there a way to have my MacBook share its Ethernet connection over WiFi so that the iPad can load pages hosted on the Linux server?

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you are looking to share your ethernet connection to Wi-Fi devices, this is possible although there is an exception where your ethernet connection implements authentication, but your Mac will state this.

To get started:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Navigate to Sharing
3. Enable Internet Sharing (left hand list)
4. Set the "Share your connection from:" dropdown to your ethernet port
5. Check the "Wi-Fi" option in the list "To computers using:"
6. Click "Wi-Fi Options" and configure the options for the network you'd like to create
7. Press "OK"

Now try connecting a device to the newly created Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's the approach I attempted as stated in my question. And the iPad is able to connect to the macbook just fine. But I'm not able to access the Linux server from the iPad.

Comment: I see, I am sorry the question was hard to read and I didn't understand. In this case the issue is that your iPad has no route to the device. Unfortunately I don't have a setup where I could test and resolve this, however the alternative solution would be a compact Wi-Fi travel router: https://www.tp-link.com/uk/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR802N.html